# How to solve x^2 - y^2 = 2000^2 using filter, map, lambda?

Tags: python, functional-programming

```
import numpy as np

#defining range
start = -5000000
end = abs(start)

x = np.linspace(start, end, abs(start) + end + 1)
y = np.linspace(start, end, abs(start) + end + 1)

print(x, y)

xy_dif_list1 = list(filter(lambda r: r == 2000**2, list(map(lambda a, b: a**2 - b**2, x, y))))

print(len(xy_dif_list1))
```

I wanted to find the number of x and y values that satisfy the equation:
x^2 - y^2 = 2000^2,
but this code is not working, because, I can see some results when I use nested for-loops:

```
xy_list = []
for x in range(-5000000, 5000000):
    for y in range(-5000000, 5000000):
        if x**2 - y**2 == (2000**2):
            xy_list.append((x, y))
            print(xy_list)

print(len(xy_list))
```

What is wrong with the filter(), map() and lambda functions?

Comment: Why don't use `(ind, ) = np.where(x**2 - y**2 == 2000**2)` ? It's fast and readable

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? I suppose it may spend too much time for Python to change your `map(lambda a, b: a**2 - b**2, x, y)`(more than 5 000 000 integers) into list. It can also take a lot of memory - M(O(N)).

Comment: map(lambda) returned 0, and just tried np.where() now, but it also returned 0 in -5m, 5m range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right way to implement what you're doing is

import itertools

```python
# find [x, y] with x^2 - y^2 = target
def solve(target):
    # assumes target >= 1, not hard to adjust to solve for all
    xmax = (target+1)//2
    x = range(xmax + 1) # 0 to xmax
    y = range(xmax) # 0 to xmax - 1
    xy = itertools.product(x, y)
    soln = filter(lambda v: v[0]*v[0] - v[1]*v[1] == target, xy)
    return list(soln)

print(solve(1000))
#print(solve(2000*2000))
```

but it's much too slow for your input number, as you need to construct and filter a 4 million-item list. Better is

```python
import math

def issquare(n):
    if (n < 0):
        return False
    m = math.isqrt(n)
    return m*m == n

# x^2 - y^2 = target
def solve2(target):
    # assumes target >= 1, not hard to adjust to solve for all
    xmax = (target+1)//2
    x = range(xmax + 1) # 0 to xmax
    soln = filter(lambda x: issquare(x*x - target), x)
    return list(map(lambda x: (x, math.isqrt(x*x - target)), soln))

print(solve2(1000))
print(solve2(2000*2000))
```

which lets you iterate only over one number. (There are further improvements available if needed.)

Comment: to find the all integers, I adjusted x as:
x = range(-xmax-1, xmax+1)

but, cannot obtain negative y values

Comment: If (x,y) is a solution so are (-x,y), (x,-y), and (-x,-y).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) doesn't create nested loops out of its iterable arguments. Instead, it steps through both of them sequentially *in parallel*, as though using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

So, you are applying the function to (x[0],  y[0]), then (x[1], y[1]), then (x[2], y[2]), etc.

You should take a look at [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the functional equivalent of nested loops.